# Position a \graph in a tikz picture (relatively)

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, graphs

I want to draw two graphs combined (actually, it is a large tree that does not fit on the page, see bonus question). However, I cannot find a way to position a `\graph`.

Here is an example:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}%
        [level distance=10mm,text depth=.1em,text height=.5em]
        \graph[tree layout, grow=up]{
          x -- {y,z}
        };
        \graph[tree layout, grow=down]{
          a -- {b,c}
        };
      \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How does one put a node between `x` and `a` (i.e. have x above that node and a below)?

Bonus question: As mentioned, the reason for my question is that I want to layout a tree that does not fit on one page. My idea is to move one sub tree upwards and turn it around. Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this via `\graph`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use what the manual calls *sublayouts* to draw your graph, like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees,graphdrawing.layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[level distance=10mm,text depth=.1em,text height=.5em]
        \graph[layered layout]{
            //[tree layout, grow=up] { x -- {y,z} };
            x -- A -- a;
            //[tree layout, grow=down] { a -- {b,c} };

        };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\graph` is just `\path graph`, so you could do `\path (x,y) graph...` to position them. The default coordinate is (0,0) I'd think.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}%
        [level distance=10mm,text depth=.1em,text height=.5em]
        \node (a) {A};
        \path (0,0.5) graph[tree layout, grow=up]{
          x -- {y,z}
        };
        \path (0,-0.5) graph[tree layout, grow=down]{
          a -- {b,c}
        };
      \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work with `Cartesian placement` strategy.

Comment: @ScumCoder I'm not really an expert on this stuff, so if you're wondering if it's possible to make it work with `Cartesian placement`, I suggest you ask a new question with an example showing that it doesn't.

Comment: My comment was in no way a complaint or criticism, I just wanted to save time for people with the same problem as me if they stumble upon your question and think that it's the solution.

I created a question for my own problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492357/how-to-start-cartesian-placement-from-existing-node).