# Position a \graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Shouldn't the following `\graph {a}` be positioned at node `middle`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
  \node (middle) at (1,1) {};
  \path[draw] (middle) circle (.5);
  \path[draw] (middle) graph {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I read answer [Position a \graph in a tikz picture (relatively)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355158/position-a-graph-in-a-tikz-picture-relatively) but it isn't working as advertised.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `graph` operation here when you can use the `nodes` as well: `path[draw] (middle) node {a}` ?

Comment: `graph {a}` is just an example. Imagine a complex graph instead.

Comment: Okay, can you complete the question with this sample graph?

Comment: I don't think the complexity of the graph is the issue here, but why `graph` isn't being positioned at the _coordinate_. This graph could be also generate inside a long path, and I would expect it to be positioned at the last specified _coordinate_.

Comment: The minimal example should reproduce the problem. In this case, it is only a syntax error since the problem can be solved without using graphs.

Comment: I believe I wrote a minimal example. The issue isn't how to write this graph using nodes, but positioning graphs using coordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You are right, at least I confirm your observation. One thing that does work, though, is to use `shift`, (Thanks to Andrew for pushing me. ;-)

- either in a scope (example `b`)
- or just in the path (example `c`).

(I tried various options, compiled with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` with and without `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`, the result on my machine was always the same: the graph sat at the origin. Most likely I am missing something, otherwise that would be the first time I would see an answer by Torbjørn that is not 100% accurate, so I guess I am doing something stupid.)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
  \coordinate (middle) at (1,1) {};
  \path[draw] (middle) circle (.5);
  \path[draw] (middle) graph {a};
  \begin{scope}[shift={(middle)}]
   \path[draw] graph {b};
  \end{scope} 
  \path[shift={(2,2)}] graph {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that you can avoid the use of `scope` entirely by using `\path[shift=(middle)] graph {a};`. This is implicit in your answer, with the graph `c`,  but it's kind of hidden since your answer suggests that you need the `scope` environment. In fact, I posted this as a follow-up answer, which I just deleted, because I didn't notice this in your post.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, this is how my lowest example `c` works. I wrote ", or just use shift" to indicate that option. I will be happy to make it clearer. I am actually concerned that I am doing something stupid. so far I have never seen any answer by Torbjørn that was not 100% accurate, so I am not sure if my answer will stay.

Comment: Per my manual reading, I think the positioning of `graph` inside a path should work. This might be a bug.