# How to start Cartesian placement from existing node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I use the `graphs` library to create graphs.
The Cartesian placement is a very convenient tool for my needs.

Sometimes I need to place a new node relative to an existing node that was automatically created by `\graph`, and then start a new node chain from it:

[image: needed]

Unfortunately the online strategy apparently starts the logical width from the first node *which was automatically created in this `\graph`*:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[SCbox/.style={rectangle,draw=black}]

    \graph[grow right sep=10mm]
    {
        A[SCbox] ->
        B[SCbox];
    };

    \node (C) [SCbox, below=of B] {C};

    \graph[grow right sep=10mm]
    {
        (C) ->
        D[SCbox];
    };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: got]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position a \graph in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450489/position-a-graph-in-tikz), if the position of the C-D chain doesn't have to be exactly 1cm from the A-B chain.

Comment: Is `\tikz\graph[branch down sep=10mm, grow right sep=10mm, nodes={rectangle,draw=black}]{A -> {B, C[not source] -> D}};` a valid approach?

Answer (score 3):

I do not really know why one would expect that the above works. IMHO one needs to shift the full graph (but I may be wrong). At least this seems to work, and it will continue to work for more complex graphs.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[SCbox/.style={rectangle,draw=black}]

    \graph[grow right sep=10mm]
    {
        A[SCbox] ->
        B[SCbox];
    };

    \coordinate[below=of B.west](aux);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(aux)}]  
   \graph[grow right sep=10mm]
    {
        C[SCbox] ->
        D[SCbox];
    };
 \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want to have 1cm distance (but this is not the point here):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[SCbox/.style={rectangle,draw=black}]

    \graph[grow right sep=10mm]
    {
        A[SCbox] ->
        B[SCbox];
    };

    \coordinate[below=of B.south west](aux);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(aux)}]  
   \graph[grow right sep=10mm]
    {[nodes={anchor=north west}]
        C[SCbox] ->
        D[SCbox];
    };
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I stress that I do not think that this is the point of the question, and it is not of the answer. My interpretation of the question is that the OP want to "reset the origin of the path", and this can be done by scoping. It is most likely clear to the OP that this very graph can be achieved in much simpler terms, but my interpretation is that the OP want to position complex graphs in one tikzpicture. And this can be achieved by putting these in scopes. One can simplify and modify and obscure this in many ways.

Comment: _> I do not really know why one would expect that the above works._

Because such semantics seem logical.

_> IMHO one needs to shift the full graph_

These are parts of one and the same graph. I connect them later.